# can we set margin of various controls depending on different resolution scales in windows 8 application using c#

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, scale, resolution

Can we set margin of various controls depending on different resolution scales in Windows 8  application using C#?

I have tried dictionary object for `ResolutionScale`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out the [ViewBox control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.aspx).  My teammate Jeff wrote a great post on it [here](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2013/03/16/lessons-learned-in-windows-8-scaling/).  Basically, you can put items in a ViewBox, and then the ViewBox will scale them appropriately within that amount of space.